# Auto-linking of Bible verses

Tags: feature-request

I undertand the technical design of this network well and I am developer by background, so I think I know why this is a no-go, but I wanted to suggest something that I think would be greatly helpful.

On my blog I use a service call [Reftagger](http://www.logos.com/reftagger) that automatically adds a javascript pop-up with an excerpt from a Bible verse and a link to an online Bible when a standard formatted verse is cited. Could we possibly see if that could be enabled here? I spend a lot of time creating links in detailed posts, it sure would be convenient.

Comment: Related: [Userscript for generating Markdown from Biblegateway.com](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have already put in a request for some [special support for verses in the markdown parser](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20/30) SE uses. Hopefully those eventually go through.

In the mean time [@dancek](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/add-markdown-and-or-onebox-support-for-biblegateway/395#395) and I have both started userscripts for inserting pre-formatted verse references. It would also be very possible to do one to add something like reftagger to this site. If you are interested in working on that let's get together on it!

Comment: Thanks! That's great, I'll look into it. The only other pitch I will make for the product I referenced is that it is 100% automated. Unlike Markdown the post author won't have to do a thing for it to work other than cite the verse in a broadly standard way.

Comment: ...which makes it an idea holdover for some of us frequent site users to implement ourselves but not a great implementation from SE's perspective.

Comment: @blundin One nice aspect of a Retagger like solution (as opposed to solely Markdown) is that the reference appears in a tooltip.  I wouldn't mind using a special markup to denote reftagger verses (to select translation, for example), as long as the tooltip support is there.