# Best way to quote verses

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you like to see scripture linked?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-would-you-like-to-see-scripture-linked)

What should be the best/encouraged way to quote verses?

I've seen people link the verse references to biblegateway.com for example. YouVersion has an easy system for linking to verses, too.

As far quoting the text, most people use quotes (with `>` in front of sentences) for long quotes.

As far as verse numbers in long quotes, some people don't style them, some others make them bold. I tend to use `<sup>1</sup>` to display them.

Should we encourage standard for these?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the other question.